# Replicating the mysql data without doing mysql sync

Tags: mysql, linux

i am trying to sync the mysql database between two machines without doing mysql sync(By mounting the mysql installed directory in the other machine). Is there any way to that operation?

Answer (score 1):

Well you can just copy the data, but why not use the facilities provided for the purpose?

Comment: We can do only one way sync (master to slave). If i have installed mysql in common partition(common space for both machines) then i have data replication in both machines without doing any extra operations –

Comment: No you don't, don't kid yourself, you have a single point of failure in the common partition.

Comment: its is EMC SAS. so common partition is accessible from other blade.

Comment: A common partition is not a synchronized replica. You've changed your objective.

Comment: Common partition is mounted on both machines. so what ever machine 1 does it will reflected in machine 2. so it is in sync.

Comment: It isn't 'in sync'. It's the *same data.* You don't have any 'reflection' or replication at all. You have a single point of failure. You've changed your objective.

Comment: Sorry after long time i am replying. i forgot the part. This is 2 blades running separately. mysql data's should be replicated in standby machine. but Mysql sycn is not advisable one because standby can be active blade and active blade can go to standby blade. So how will you replicate the data without mysql sync.